# passing prop to state in react js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

```
const [nav, setNav] = useState({
firstPage: "active",
});
```

**I want to pass my prop as value to state firstpage how I do this in correct manner**

```
const addNavi = (prop) => {

//want to pass prop in to my state value
}
```

Comment: This needs more detail

Comment: i pass some value as pops to my context from child page, i want to set that passed prop as my state value, ex:  firstPage:"value I passed as props". simply wanna replace "active" from that prop

Answer (score 3):

You can use [destructuring assignment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment) the `props` in the argument of the `AddNavi` component signature (in parenthesis) and then pass it in as the first argument in `useState`, which will set the initial state of `nav`:

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';

const AddNavi = ({ firstPage }) => {

  const [nav, setNav] = useState(firstPage);
}
```

***Hint***: ReactJS components **MUST** start with upper case characters like `AddNav` not `addNav`.

Answer (score 2):

I suppose you want to initialize the state with props value, you can pass this like below.

```
const [nav, setNav] = React.useState({...props.firstPage});
```